# Inheritance is a null property in the parent a bad practice?

Tags: inheritance, null, properties

I am not a very experienced programmer. So I ask.

The field in question is the "Amount" field. I store an amount only in a couple levels of the derived class.

The code is a slice of the POCO classes that are making up my data model, the datalayer is Entity framework, code first.

I mention that because the reason I did the amount property like I did is because when I placed the Amount just in a derived class or two and not in the Navigation class, the table in the database would have an extra field for each class with an Amount property, like (Amount, Amount1, Amount2). I did not like that.

So after screwing around with the code for awhile I discovered that...

Placing the Amount property in the navigation class and overriding it in the classes that implemented Amount gave me a table with just one "Amount" field that was Null, unless it was one of the classes that used amount in which case it had a value, which was just what I wanted. I liked that.

So the question is, is the way the Amount property is handled completely proper or have some downside?

```
public class Navigation
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Title { get; set; }
    string Description { get; set; }
    ObservableCollection<Navigation> Children { get; set; }

    public virtual decimal? Amount
    {
        get { return null; }
        set { value = null; }
    }
}
public class C1 : Navigation { }
public class C2 : Navigation { }
public class C3 : Navigation
{
    private decimal _amount;
    public override decimal? Amount
    {
        get { return _amount; }
        set { if (value != null) _amount = (decimal)value; }
    }
}
public class C4 : Navigation
{
    private decimal _amount;
    public override decimal? Amount
    {
        get { return _amount; }
        set { if (value != null) _amount = (decimal)value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me answer your question with a question.  How would you like it if your TV's remote had buttons that never do anything...just because the TV makers planned on building a TV that they would work on?

Comment: I get that concept. Just to clarify, The Amount property should not be a virtual property in the navigation class but simply a property in the c3 and c4 classes?

Comment: @Jon Do you ever create instances of `Navigation` itself?

Comment: Yes. One in the DB init looks like this:

            foreach (Navigation navigation in context.Navigations)
            {
                navigation.Lein = -1;
                navigation.Overflow = 1;
                navigation.Amount = 1;
            }

Comment: @Dan1701 Also in a WPF UI the primary data binding is to the DbSet<Navigation>. However Navigation as an entity in itself  is never used.

Comment: @cHao ....my remote does have those buttons....

Comment: @cHao Mine also, for the VCR, I don't have a VCR.

Comment: @Jon: At the very least, IMO the property in the base class should not have a setter.  But yeah, if `Amount` only really makes sense for `c3` and `c4`, then it should probably only exist on those classes.

Comment: @cHao Why? I am still wondering the risks? (not that I don't respect your IMO).

Comment: @Jon: Because setters that don't actually set anything violate the Principle of Least Surprise.  Most people expect a read/write property to act at least superficially like a field;  if they can say `o.Prop = 1;`, then a subsequent `o.Prop == 1` should be true.  A do-nothing setter breaks that expectation, and makes it harder to know what stuff like `navigation.Amount = 1;` actually does.

Comment: Why would a class called Navigation have an amount? Amount of what ? Also what language is that ?

Comment: Amount is $. Navigation is the parent class, That other classes derive from. C#. Essentially the money flows down through the hierarchy, every level splits it up to the kids. Amount is the storage, only used in a couple of classes toward the bottom. It is explained in framing the question how it got there.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Removing the Amount field from the Navigation left me with another problem described and posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26191093/designing-model-for-a-field-in-code-first-entity-framework-that-is-null-for-cert

Comment: I haven't used EF much. I just did a quick Google and it seems possible to map protected fields. If you make amount protected you can just make the Amount property backed by the protected field in the classes that actually needs it. It is not ideal but might be better than alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a not good practice because people expect something when they see the property in the class. Imagine if someone writes:

```
var n = new Navigation (...);
n.Amount = 123.45;
......
Console.WriteLine(n.Amount); //null? why???
```

A better approach would be to at least warn them:

```
public virtual decimal Amount{
    get { return new NotSupportedException("Amount is not supported in this class."); }
    set { //same as above }
}
```

But now you'd get the C# practice warning: "properties should behave like fields and should never throw exceptions".

Perhaps you can add a `Type` field, then throw away inheritance altogether. But I'm not sure if this is appropriate for your scenario (maybe you have lots of extra fields in derived classes).

---

Of course, if you're not writing a library that will be used by lots of other programmers, *there's nothing wrong to bend common practices*. **Be flexible**.

*Do you find it confusing to yourself?* If it works and you're comfortable with it, go ahead.

---

What would I do? This is one of the down sides of Entity Framework, which I don't really like anyway. To me, it brings more problems than it solves. I'd just create tables in the DB, create the classes as you wish in C#, then write some helper methods to map them. If all you do is `SELECT` and `INSERT`, it's not as hard as you may think. It's outside the scope of this site, but I guarantee you it's around ~50 lines (I've done it).

Comment: I love EF, and yes it is a source of headaches. The way I did this was not confusing to me, it solved an entity problem, however it did not feel right. But making it right reintroduced my original problem. I thought this problem was an entity problem, so I posted in stack overflow. Turns out that it was in the inheritance to fix it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26191093/designing-model-for-a-field-in-code-first-entity-framework-that-is-null-for-cert

Comment: I was more of thinking like, you'd need the base class to establish some common functionality. Yea removing inheritance works as well if you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do if you want to add a property to only a few of the subclasses is to use another interface. In your example: Navigation -> AmountEnabledNavigation -> C3, but Navigation -> C1. In the code that handles the objects, e.g. adds the amounts, you can simply check if the object inherits from AmountEnabledNavigation and then decide based on that.

This also prevents later issues like exceptions when accessing the objects. Although these can be caught and handled, they slow down code considerably.